# what happens if interrupt occurs while ISR running?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, interrupt

I am programming arduino, I attached an interrupt on pin2 falling edge. While I am in the ISR and the ISR has not executed all the lines. Before finishing all the lines if falling edge comes again what happens? Does interrupt start from begining or ignor it. Here I am talking about only interrupt on pin2.

Comment: I don't know about Arduino specifically, but many small CPUs disable interrupts while another interrupt is in progress. That's an important reason to keep ISRs as short an fast as possible. Many other CPUs have interrupts of different priorities, so that an interrupt of a higher priority can interrupt lower-priority interrupts. You should read the specifications for the CPU on your Arduino board.

Comment: In general, keep your ISR as small and short as possible, a good ISR might be to just set a flag that the main loop will check for.

Comment: my sensor debounces, so always can't depend on interrupt alone. has to finish the calculation within interrupt so that debounces does not effect

Comment: By the way can I call a function from interrupt?

Comment: Handling debouncing buttons inside an ISR is definitely something you should *not* do. It's easy to handle in code outside of the ISR anyway (just ignore multiple button presses within a certain time period). And yes, you can call functions from inside the ISR, though you should be careful not to call any that can cause further interrupts as that can lead to a deadlock.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Handling debouncing buttons inside an ISR is definitely something you should not do.` Could you please tell us why not? In the case of a button press, I thought it was perfectly reasonable to start the ISR with an `if ()` to check if enough times has elapsed since the last button press before doing anything else.

Comment: @pfabri I don't know what I must have been thinking, because as you say it would be a *good* place to add a simple condition to check for it. However it's only a good place iff one can get and compare times in a quick and simple way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Atmel processor disables interrupts when an interrupt is taken:

(Section 4.4: Bit 7 – I: Global Interrupt Enable)

> The Global Interrupt Enable bit must be set for the interrupts to be
>   enabled. The individual interrupt enable control is then performed
>   in separate control registers. If the Global Interrupt Enable Register
>   is cleared, none of the interrupts are enabled independent of the
>   individual interrupt enable settings. The I-bit is cleared by hardware
>   after an interrupt has occurred, and is set by the RETI instruction to
>   enable subsequent interrupts. The I-bit can also be set and cleared by
>   the application with the SEI and CLI instructions, as described in the
>   instruction set reference.

Further:

> External Interrupt Flag Register – EIFR
>
> • Bits 7..0 – INTF6, INTF3 - INTF0: External Interrupt Flags 6, 3 - 0
>   When an edge or logic change on the INT[6;3:0] pin triggers an
>   interrupt request, INTF7:0 becomes set (one). If the I-bit in SREG and
>   the corresponding interrupt enable bit, INT[6;3:0] in EIMSK, are set
>   (one), the MCU will jump to the interrupt vector. The flag is cleared
>   when the interrupt routine is executed. Alternatively, the flag can be
>   cleared by writing a logical one to it. These flags are always cleared
>   when INT[6;3:0] are configured as level interrupt. Note that when
>   entering sleep mode with the INT3:0 interrupts disabled, the input
>   buffers on these pins will be disabled. This may cause a logic change
>   in internal signals which will set the INTF3:0 flags.

In other words, when another interrupt is detected, the flag register will have that bit set, and that interrupt taken when interrupts are enabled again (at return from interrupts if no separate action is taken).

http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_%20Datasheet.pdf

If you want to, you could implement code that enables interrupt during that interrupt service routine, but you have to make sure that the code after such a point is fully re-entrant, and/or mask the current interrupt (some interrupt service routines are pretty darn hard to handle when you don't get another interrupt soon after, and it gets almost impossible if you get another one when you are currently in that handler). However, it is often the case for proper operating systems to enable all other interrupts - which means writing to the EIMSK register.

As a general rule, it's best to simply collect the necessary information in the interrupt handler, store it away in "safe" place (circular buffers are good for this), and signal that new data is available to a regular task in the system, and process the data there.

[Additionally, as far as I can tell, there is nothing stopping function calls inside an interrupt - as long as you understand what you are doing and there is no problems for example from calling the function from both the interrupt and the regular code at the same time]

Comment: +1, I can confirm that calling functions in an interrupt-handler is just fine. As @Mats says, non-local data accessed from the function may be an issue if it can be reentered from multiple, nested interrupts or from interrupt and user states, eg. the set of OS system functions that can be safely called is very small.